# Semi log plot axis labelling and function doesn't appear in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a plot with a log axis in x, going from 10^-8 to 10^-3, with only every other ticks labelled, and an y axis from 0 to 100.
I can't manage to label every other tick, and the function doesn't appear on the graph
Does anyone know where I've gone wrong?

## Parameters

```
c4=1e-6
c5=2
K3=1e-6
R1=0.02
R2=0.05
R3=0.2
```

## Function

```
g <- function(x,c5,K3,R,c4)
{
z = (c5*K3*x)/(R*c4-c5*x)
return(z)
}

z1 <- g(x, c5, K3, R1, c4)
z2 <- g(x, c5,K3,R2,c4)
z3 <- g(x, c5,K3,R3,c4)
```

## Plot

```
plot(x, z1, log="x", lty=3, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlim=c(10^-8, 10^-3), ylim=c(0, 100),
 main="Fig 2B", 
 xlab="[Ca2+] in cytosol (M)",
 ylab="[InsP3] (nM))")
 axis(side=2, at= seq(0,100, by=10), labels= c(0, FALSE, 20, FALSE,  40, FALSE, 60, FALSE, 80, FALSE, 100), srt=90)
 xticks <- seq(-7, -3, by=2)
 xlabels <- sapply(xticks, function(i) as.expression(bquote(10^ .(i))))
 axis(side=1, at=c(10^-7, 10^-5, 10^-3), labels=xlabels)
 lines(x, z2, lty=2)
 lines(x, z3, lty=1)
```

Comment: Your example is not completely reproducible, you didn't provide `x` input vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions to this problem:

1) Set every other label to NA (not FALSE as you tried)

```
plot(1:10, axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = 1:10, labels = c(NA, 2, NA, 4, NA, 6, NA, 8, NA, 10))
```

2) Add the axis twice. Once without labels to get just the tick marks, and once with the labels you want

```
plot(1:10, axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = 1:10, labels = FALSE)
axis(1, at = seq(2, 10, 2))
```